# MongoDB: how to get max and min values for every category? I received null value

Tags: mongodb, group-by, null, max, min

I need to find max and min flight_time for every line.

That's part of my collection (it's only two documents, but I have sth like 20):

```
db.myflights.insert([
//1
{
    start_time: new Date("2020-05-18T06:15:00Z"),
    land_time: new Date("2020-05-18T07:30:00Z"),
    flight_time: 1.25, 
    passengers: "90",
    line_name: "WizzAir"
},
//2
{
    start_time: new Date("2020-06-18T07:30:00Z"),
    land_time: new Date("2020-06-18T09:30:00Z"),
    flight_time: 2, 
    passengers: "111",
    line_name: "Lufthansa"
}
])
```

I tried:

```
db.myflights.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$line_name"}},

    {
    $addFields:
    {"max_time": {$max: "$flight_time"}  }
            },
    {
    $addFields:
    {"min_time": {$min: "$flight_time"} }
            }

])
```

I received null in both of the max/min_time.

do you have any advices how can I change that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the `$max` and `$min` as part of the `$group` stage.

Try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$line_name",
      max_time: {
        $max: "$flight_time"
      },
      min_time: {
        $min: "$flight_time"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bwtPUN6qaON)